# Mandar variable PHP a tabla en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

me gustaria mandar mediante un `INSERT INTO` estas variables php que imprimo en tablas de html, pero no se como hacerlo o si se puede

Os dejo un ejemplo de una de las tablas que tengo

```
    <!-- Jornada 1 -->
  <p><b>Jornada:</b> 1</p>
  <p><b>Fecha de encuentro:</b> <?php echo $start ?></p>

<table class="table">
  <thead align="center" class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Local</th>
      <th scope="col">Visitante</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody align="center">
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" value="<?php echo $eq7;?>"><?php echo $name7 ?></td>
      <td value="<?php echo $eq8;?>"><?php echo $name8 ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" value="<?php echo $eq9;?>"><?php echo $name9 ?></td>
      <td value="<?php echo $eq4;?>"><?php echo $name4 ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td value="<?php echo $eq5;?>"><?php echo $name5 ?></td>
      <td value="<?php echo $eq2;?>"><?php echo $name2 ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" value="<?php echo $eq1;?>"><?php echo $name1 ?></td>
      <td value="<?php echo $eq6;?>"><?php echo $name6 ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" value="<?php echo $eq3;?>"><?php echo $name3 ?></td>
      <td value="<?php echo $eq10;?>"><?php echo $name10 ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- Fin jornada 1 -->
```

Las variables que tengo que mandar son ids, como por ejemplo el `$eq7` (Aun que no se si esto se puede hacer)

¿Podriais ayudarme?

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se entiende muy bien lo que necesitas, pero creo que te refieres a crear una conexión con la base de datos para guardar en una tabla los valores $eqX, pero no nos dices cómo es tu base de datos ni nada, así que mi ejemplo no te valdrá tal cual y tendrás que adaptarlo a tus necesidades. Pero básicamente se trata de conectar con la base de datos y realizar el insert:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario_base_de_datos", "contraseña_base_de_datos", "nombre_base_de_datos");
    if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    $mysqli->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO tabla (%d, %d)", $eq1, $eq2));
?>
```

Esto insertará en la base de datos los valores $eq1 y $eq2 en una tabla llamada tabla que se presume tiene los campos eq1 y eq2. Lógicamente, tienes que crear la tabla con los campos adicionales que quieras y modificar la línea del INSERT para añadir los campos.

También decir que se puede hacer así (inseguro) o usando PDO (más seguro) y en cualquier caso, deberías revisar este enlace que habla sobre SQL Injection: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Lo que busco de alguna manera es mandar los id que tengo traidos de un inner join que previamente hice, simplemente necesito saber si puedo meterlos... Pero creo que tengo una solucion a raiz de tu respuesta, si no, intentare abrir un hilo con mas detalle

Comment: Si planteas una nueva pregunta o editas esta con más información, estaremos encantados de ayudarte nuevamente.